# Rumex? Burdock? Perennial fast-grower has us stumped in Illinois

Tags: identification, perennials

I figured this would be an easy ID given the size of the leaves, segmented stem, and such but haven't been able to nail it down.

The fence pictured is 5 feet tall.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks a bit (but maybe not quite) like rhubarb...? The ochrea indicates a Polygonaceae, which would fit your suggestion of Rumex or Rheum.

Comment: @Stephie, interesting. Maybe the Riverside Giant variety?

Comment: Not quite - the leave shape is a touch too triangular and especially the “falling apart” of the leaves is not quite garden/cooking rhubarb-ish. But am leaning towards Rheum...? Can’t give a good id, hence the comments, not an answer. Sorry!

Comment: Looks like rhubarb grown in shade and gone to seed

Comment: @Stephie - well,  rhubarb is a Rheum, so I think you should post it as an answer. Personally, I don't think it's a Rumex (leaves too broad and not pointed enough, and the flowers are too "fancy"). I agree with kevinsky - it's rhubarb, perhaps an old variety that never was very red to begin with. The rhubarb we grew in Milwaukee, WI in the 1960s was planted in the late 1920s and had very green stalks. It was tasty, though.

Comment: @Jurp I know that rhubarb is a Rheum, but not all Rheums are the kitchen type. Before id-ing something that may end up in a pie, I‘d like to be reasonably sure...

Comment: Well, if it's not sour, it's probably not rhubarb. :) If it is sour, it might be rhubarb (but not necessarily). I'm not advocating consuming it, without knowing.

Comment: @Stephie - I meant that you could give it a Rheum ID. Rereading my answer, I can see that it was advocating for a rhubarb ID (I agree that when it comes to edible plants, you must be 100% sure). This was a good question for me because I had to do some rhubarb research (not of the culinary kind, unfortunately). I was surprised at how many "rhubarb" species there actually are. I'd like to get my hands on a Rheum palmatum myself - supposed to be better tasting than our common varieties.

Comment: This is definitely not culinary rhubarb that I'm familiar with (UK), but judging by the leaves, stems and flowers, it is certainly a relative